# how sort by name in json response

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Simple thing i am taking users and want to sort by name. Yea it is very easy

```
User::where('status_symbol', User::ACTIVE)->orderBy('name')->get()->pluck('full_name', 'id')
```

full name is attribute from user model

```
public function getFullNameAttribute() {
    return $this->name . ' ' . $this->surname;
}
```

and results are ok. Now i want send to view (vue) but somehow js sorting again by id as default.

```
return response()->json(User::where('status_symbol', User::ACTIVE)->orderBy('name')->get()->pluck('full_name', 'id'));
```

but if i sent without id seems ok, how can make sort by `full_name` after send response to vue?

```
axios.get('/api/users/get/all')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.reps = response.data
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error('Failed to load users')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) over your results, which give you `id => full_name` results. Your call should be:

```php
User::where('status_symbol', User::ACTIVE)
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->get('name', 'surname', 'id')
    ->only(['full_name', 'id']);
```